# Is it possible to make a custom currency field editable only if standard list price field is zero on opportunity products?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I tried creating a validation rule using IsNull, ISBlank and even"" but none of them work so I suspect I am writing it in the wrong way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the standard list price field show as "$0.00" or does it the value populate as an empty or blank field?

Comment: It shows as "$0.00".

Comment: Are you using OOB Opportunity Product `New Product` to create OLI or do you have a custom VF page to enter opportunity Line Items (OLI)?

Comment: Hi, we are using the standard opp product page. Sorry took this long to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a value of $0.00, then your validation rule's formula needs to reflect that. Your rule that makes the other field 'required' should probably look something like the following:

```
NOT(If(ListPrice = 0.00, Currency__c > 0.00, IsBlank(Currency__c)))
```

You'll want to put the NOT in front since it's a validation rule. I've made the assumption that Currency__c is normally blank or empty when not populated. If it's `0.00`, your formula should reflect that. This could also be rewritten to something like below:

```
If(ListPrice != 0.00, Currency__c > 0.00, IsBlank(Currency__c) )
```

The above would require the currency field to be empty when ListPrice has a value and greater than zero when it doesn't.

Note: the page layout is what makes the field editable. If you need to make it conditionally editable, you'll need to do something with conditional sharing rules that adds Edit permissions to the field for Users in a Group through a permission set.

Comment: This modification worked for me. NOT(IF(ListPrice = 0.00, NOT(ISBLANK(Intl_ManualListPrice__c)), ISBLANK(Intl_ManualListPrice__c))). But many many thanks for your help! Appreciate it.